# How to detect rectangle in noisy image - OpenCV using HoughTransform or other method?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have images(sometime scanned) like this

[image] and

[image]
and

[image].

I want to identify first two large rectangle at first and then last three smaller rectangle at second. I googled and found that i have to locate corner of the rectangle and use that info to indentify rectangle. But I am not sure how to approach this problem and handle noisy image like these.

I came across [this tutorial](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) to detect line and somehow I managed to run this.

I am just starting in Computer Vision. I would appreciate any help/pointer to sample code/documentation.

**Update:** I managed to run this on my image.

Now I am getting this[image].

Any idea how to get the check if there is at least two larger or three smaller adjacent rectangles?

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("4.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# canny edge detection
edges = cv2.Canny(img, 0, 200, apertureSize=2)

minLineLength = 100
maxLineGap = 10
lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 1, np.pi/180, 100, minLineLength, maxLineGap)

for i in range(len(lines)):
    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in lines[i]:
        cv2.line(img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (0, 255, 0), thickness=2)


cv2.imwrite('22.jpeg', img)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't you think it would make sense to start with good images if you're a beginner?

Comment: Yes, @Piglet. Apology if it looks offensive. I am working on page order identification from image of insurance documents(customer application form). E.g. whether the image is first page of insurance document or second page?

Comment: if you want to detect specific rectangles a simple approach would be to use OpenCV's findContours function and then filter them by the desired aspect ratio and relative size from the list of results.